# PHP SQL, query returns only one row of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

quick question... my sql query is spitting out this data...

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Test Name [text] => This is text [image] => image.jpg )
```

When there are two rows of data, is there something wrong with my php code?

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, text, image FROM categories";
    $results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches one row at a time.  You need to loop over the result set:

```
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))){
    [handle $row here]
}
```

From the docs (search is your friend):

> Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the same name, you either need to access the result with numeric indices by using mysql_fetch_row() or add alias names. See the example at the mysql_fetch_array() description about aliases.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Madbreakers for you're help

Comment: 'Thanks' is nice but you'll probably want to up-vote any answers that you found helpful, and accept the one you think best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The fetch functions only return a single row at a time. If you want all the rows, you'll have to use a loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
   ... do stuff with $row
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B for you're help

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc($results) does only fetches one row.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Incomplete answer. You need to provide the way to get all rows, as this is obviously what the OP wants.

Comment: I thought the example in the link was enough.