# Assuming there's a "date" column and a "name" column, how to get only the "names" before "current date"?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SQL, query returns only one row of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644212/php-sql-query-returns-only-one-row-of-data)

A friend of mine is asked me to do some coding. **He created a MySQL database with columns "gameName" (VARCHAR) and "releaseDate" (date). He needs to fetch and show the game names from "gameName" which are released before current date.**

Here I have used MySQL's *CURDATE()* function to filter out already released games. But the problem is I have to write an echo line for each results. It's bad programming and the logic behind that is very bad.

```
<?php
$mysql_host="host_name";
$mysql_username="db_user";
$mysql_password="db_password";
$mysql_database="db_name";
$mysql_table="table_name";

mysql_connect("host_name", "db_user", "db_password") or die("YOLO");
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("YOLO");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT gameName FROM table_name WHERE CURDATE() > releaseDate");
$result = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

echo $result[0];
echo $result[1];
echo $result[2];
// and so on...?
?>
```

Result: Only one record showed up.

Comment: There's a thing called *loops*. At least start by reading the examples in the PHP manual: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Also, refrain to use the `mysql*` class of function in new code, as [they are now deprecated](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use [mysqli](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO example,

```
   $config = array(
        'host'  => 'hostname',
        'db'    => 'db_name',
        'user'  => 'db_user',
        'pass'  => 'db_pass'
    );

    try{

        $PDO = new PDO(
            'mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['db'],
            $config['user'],
            $config['pass']
        );

        $query = $PDO->query("
                    SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE CURDATE() > releaseDate"
            );
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        while($game = $query->fetch()){
            echo $game->gameName;
        }   

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    unset($PDO);
```

Comment: Thanks Kasun. This worked fine. The only thing I had to add was a dead simple:
echo "<br />";

Comment: You are welcome! for more example check http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access this link

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer. I strongly recommend the PDO library, especially if you will be dealing with user input.

If you insist on sticking with `mysql_*`, your code should look more like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("your query") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row['gameName'] . '<br />';
}
```

I agree with the above comments though. I recommend you really read up on the manuals before you get too involved. Having that little bit of extra knowledge can make a big difference to your efficiency as a programmer (not to mention the security of your code).